# Power Automate: Export to Data Lake Business Events Alerts

Tags: power-automate, azure-data-lake, businessevents

Essentially, we are trying to use get a notification whenever a table from export to data lake changes state (i.e., deactivated) as described in this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/data-entities/azure-data-lake-generates-biz-events

We have installed the Dynamics 365 Export to Data Lake solution in the Power Platform admin center and can see the Catalog and Category as intended. However, we are getting the error message: “Could not retrieve values. Did not find any entities for catalog 'msdynedl_catalog' and category 'msdynedl_dataexportcategory'.” when trying to finalize the setup (Data Lake is also set up and running): (https://i.stack.imgur.com/C32m8.png)

I have gone to Data Management > Framework parameters > Refresh entity list and subsequently ‘Rebuilt business event catalog’ without success.

If I add (none) into the field as per Microsoft's documentation, I get the following error a step later: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUFbJ.png)
Or filling in all steps:
"Flow save failed with code 'DynamicOperationRequestClientFailure' and message 'The dynamic operation request to API 'commondataserviceforapps' operation 'GetMetadataForActionInputAndResponseForWhenAnActionIsPerformedTrigger' failed with status code 'NotFound'. This may indicate invalid input parameters. Error response: {"error":{"code":"EntityNotFound","message":"Could not find table with name '(none)'."}}'."

I have gone to Data Management > Framework parameters > Refresh entity list and subsequently ‘Rebuilt business event catalog’ without success. The desired business events are not showing up even after enabling the D365 Export to Data Lake solution in the Power Platform admin center as per the documentation.

I cannot figure out how to resolve this issue. Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: The issue was that the listed environment was not actually the correct one but just a user created one. An admin had to go in and activate the Export to Data Lake Add-in in the Power Platform Admin center and then set up the connection themselves in Power Automate, as the environment would only be visible to the admin user. The rest populated as expected after this change.

Also, ensure to link the environment in the Power Platform Admin center as well as confirm that the Export to Data Lake Add-in is successfully installed.